# Do matrix multiplication and inner product commute?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n, X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, is  the following statement true and why?

$$\langle aX, b \rangle = \langle a, bX^T\rangle$$

Comment: what do you think ?

Comment: The dimensions are not compatible.

Comment: i do verify it's true by some numpy code, but not sure how to prove it in a elegant way

Comment: How to multiply if $d \neq n$ ?

Comment: $a,b$ are row vectors, d=n? Otherwise $aX$ does not make sense.



Then $<a,b>=ab^T$. Then you want $aXb^T=a(bX^T)^T=aXb^T$ which is true.

Comment: @dmtri sorry $n=d$, that is a mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you mean $(Xa, b) = (a, X^Tb)$ for all $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$. This is the defining property of the linear transformation $X^T$, called the adjoint of $X$. This means that $X^T$ has this property and is the only linear transformation that has this property. To prove uniqueness, let $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and plug in $a = e_i$, $b = e_j$ to get $(Xe_i, e_j) = (e_i, X^Te_j)$, that is, $X_{ji} = (X^T)_{ij}$. So the entries of $X^T$ are uniquely determined. To prove existence, define $(X^T)_{ij} = X_{ji}$.